# Minecraft Server CB/Spigot Multi-version Compatibility

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, minecraft-spigot

So, this isn't necessarily a problem though, but more like a I-NEED-HELP situation. So my server is Currently running Spigot 1.7.2-1.7.5 and I was wondering if there was a way to have my server be compatible with multiple versions of Minecraft. For example, I'm running CB 1.6.4 and others on relatively new version clients can join. I'm not sure how I should do this. I checked many forums, they don't help. I also use BungeeCord if thats possible to get it to run Multiple-version compatibility.

Also I referred to the following servers, cause they can run multiple versions, just check with the `/version` command:

- Mineplex: us.mineplex.com
- Hive: play.hivemc.com
- and others.

I believe CB snapshot is being implemented, but that still doesn't solve the question. Please don't tell me I need a plugin to implement the snapshot CB. If there is no other way, tell me the ways.

Comment: Bumps are highly NOT encouraged. People see this (like me) and will answer when they know.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no ->easy<- way to get a multiple version server working. I know it would be possible but the big problem is version/packet protocol. You can not have a single server that allows for multiple versions, as you would either cause client problems for clients older than the server (problems meaning missing blocks, biomes, mobs, and the like), or the server would not be able to handle some of the newer features of minecraft in use by newer clients (new blocks could not be placed, new mobs would not spawn, new biomes would not generate).

If you wanted to have a multi-version server you would probably need a hub that detects the client-version then selects the correct protocols for a successful connection. This hub would have to then redirect players to another server that matches their version information (or is at least compatible). But as for a single server that allows full functionality for all versions, you would essentially need to rewrite the game.

Comment: Great, I understand cause I'm a techxpert. But I heard that the last successful build of Spigot does it all. Please tell me if that  is true. Then revise your answer.

Comment: @Agentleader1 Spigot has some special "protocol" builds that essentially allow for 1.7 and 1.8 clients to connect, but these builds were only being produced when Spigot 1.8 wasn't actually finished yet. Once the Spigot developers finished Spigot 1.8, they dropped support for the protocol builds. Because of the DMCA issues, it's particularly hard to find these protocol builds now too. I wouldn't recommend using them as it will likely cause you more difficulties down the road.

Answer (score -2):

I play on the buildfreeks server.  They allow multiple versions to connect and you get the same plots with all the same stuff on them no matter what version you run.  Also you can see and interact with other players running other versions all on the same server.

Comment: This is not really an answer. How does this support the question?