# How can I let people join my minecraft server from diffrent versions?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I've seen multiple servers where you can connect from any (recent) major version. (Example, 1.9, 1.8 OR 1.7) And they all seem to be able to do it. Alas, a simple google search did not fix the problem. Any ideas? Thanks guys.

(PS: The Minecraft server is running on the latest Spigot for 1.10 as of 6/27/16)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/165641/minecraft-server-cb-spigot-multi-version-compatibility?rq=1).

Comment: @Jouramue, the auestion des not have an upvote or an answer. As a result, it can not be used as an original to a duplicate. I dont see the recommendation request, here, either.

Answer (score 2):

Usually this is done with a (potentially modified) version of BungeeCord with multiple spigot servers runnning 1.7.10, 1.8.9, 1.9 and 1.10. Look into doing it that way - but you'll need a lot of resources to run multiple servers.