# How do I use a older version of Minecraft to join a server running a newer version of minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

Title says it all, I am lagging on some of the newer versions, and I would prefer to use the same version I am using. I already tried optifine and all the other stuff, so this is really my only choice. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I let people join my minecraft server from diffrent versions?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/271544/how-can-i-let-people-join-my-minecraft-server-from-diffrent-versions)

Answer (score 3):

**You can't**. Your version must match the server's version in order to connect to a server. There is no way to connect to a server with a mismatched version.

Comment: You can still keep your current version in a version profile, but if a server has latest, you need latest. See this question for more info: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/19426/how-do-i-downgrade-minecraft-to-play-on-a-server-running-an-older-version

Comment: There are server mods that allow a few versions back and forth, but I would strongly advice against them, they have strange side effects around every corner.

Comment: For example, I am easily able to use 1.12.2 on a 1.8.9 server, so no, you don't always need to match up the versions...

Comment: @user224194 Interesting... That may be a server mod of some sort. In any case, if you get a "mismatch version" error on a server, there isn't anything you can do on the client side to fix it other than change versions.

Answer (score -1):

Install ViaVersion and ViaBackwards onto the server. This will allow you to join the server on older versions of the game.